# Identify this wooden 24 hole pegboard game

Tags: identify-this-game

What game is this pegboard for?

[image: Pegboard with a row of 2-5 hole groups (10 peg holes) on each side with 4 peg holes at the top]

It has a row of 2-5 hole groups (10 peg holes) on each side with 4 peg holes at the top.

Comment: I tried googling for what's on the plaque, and it seems to be an adress to a residential area, and it looks rather home made. Seeing as it says "Games, Puzzles & Things" on the side, it might be a puzzle rather than a game. It's hard to see what the right-most word is after "Leisure Time", but looks like Crafts or something, but nothing I googled came back with any hits.

Comment: can we get a better picture of that label on the side of the board?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. You are right about the label. It was for a game and crafts company in Midland, Mi. I did a search for them but nothing showed up. This item is at least 30 years old. It was from my deceased parents home.

Comment: FWIW, I would guess that this board (with 2 colors of pegs, bilateral symmetry, 10 holes in groups of 5, some extra holes after the 10) might be for _scoring_, similar to a cribbage board, and wouldn't be the whole game in itself. (But the plaque might be counter-evidence.)

Answer (score 8):

Given the peg hole groupings and the board being football-shaped, this might be a handcrafted (American) [football dice travel game](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/240111/football-wooden-travel-game).

The group of 4 peg holes on the left track downs, and the 20 peg holes on the right track progress down the field, five yards per hole.

Each down, progress is determined for the player on offense by rolling a pair of 6-sided dice and consulting a chart indicating yards gained or lost.

Some peg boards provide tracks for players' overall scores and a track for the game's 4 quarters, but on this board scores and game time would be noted on paper.

An image search for "football dice peg board" in your favorite search engine will display several variations, for example:

[image]

Comment: @Cohensius, thank you for editing in a representative photo.  Much appreciated!